# grid based world for ant simulation

Tags: c#, simulation

I've got to create an ant simulation for a a piece of coursework.

I've got to use a "2D discrete (grid based) world" to put the ants on. the problem is that I don't know how/what that is.

I just need someone to explain and show me what that is. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: You really need to show some of your own work as we can't just do this for you but I would suggest you look into 2d arrays for this kind of thing depending on the eventual complexity.

Comment: I would put my work on here but there's nothing about the grid based world I'm after. but thanks for trying to point me in the right direction.

Comment: Ah OK no problems, like I said it depends how complex this is going to end up. If its just a simple simulation a 2D array with various int values representing "world objects" would be fine, if not it might be worth looking at XNA and the various tutorials on 2D tile engines.

Comment: yea its supposed to be really basic, like the ants are supposed to move around and find food and a nest. I can send you what I have so far if you want.

Answer (score 0):

> yea its supposed to be really basic, like the ants are supposed to move around and find food and a nest. – D Goble

Decided to post a reply to the above in a comment, like I said you wont get the exact code you need without posting some of your own but what you need to do (and research) is.

1. Simulate your world. (There are better ways of doing this but for a simple world look at a 2D array with int values representing the tile e.g. 0 = empty, 1 = ant, 2 = food, 3 = nest, 4 = obstacle)
2. Store your objects in some sort of structure with properties. (e.g. you will want an Ant object with various actions like move, eat, ect. But if this is one of your first C# projects feel free to ignore this until you are a little more comfortable)
3. A game tick to progress your game, look up game state management or game loop. (Again this depends on experience, if you want something simple a basic loop will do).
4. A basic AI for your ants, are they just going to randomly move around (unless they try to hit an obstacle) or will they seek out the nearest source of food and then return to their nest? (If so there are plenty of pathfinding examples out there)
5. Draw your game, for this just use the console no need for anything fancy. There are loads of examples of C# console games out there that will show you how to do this.

If you do a bit of Googling around each of these terms that should get you most of the way there.

Comment: `private Bitmap worldImage;

        public ASForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            randObjectForFood = new Random();

            randObjectForNest = new Random();

            randObjectForAnt = new Random();

           
            int worldWidth;
            int worldHeight;

           
            worldWidth = 800;
            worldHeight = 800;

           
            worldImage = new Bitmap(worldWidth, worldHeight);  `                     This is what I had done to make my 'world' but its not a grid based world is it.

Comment: Since the code to randomly generate your world is just a nested loop and is fairly basic, I have linked it [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4c568927c4f4924dc3e4) this will generate a 10x10 grid. After that each step is listed above, your next step could be creating an Ant object [here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/aa288470(v=vs.71).aspx)